# Perform Google Search only for premises that are currently open

Tags: google-search

This is purely hypothetical, but let's say it's a Sunday afternoon, you really fancy fish and chips for tea, but most chippies are closed on a Sunday. Googling for fish and chip shops is easy enough, but having to go through each one individually to determine if it is open or not is a laborious process.

On mobile or desktop, or any which way, but preferably Android, is there a way to filter shops and other such premises by whether they are open or not?

[image: filter image]

Comment: It would be great if down voters would explain their reasons?

Comment: More downvotes without explanation...

Comment: I'm 2.5yrs late to the party, but I suspect the downvotes were from the webapp-focus or android-focus, they both have their own SE sites. But I got here looking for how to filter on a desktop computer, so I'll +1 anyway (apparently they're only allowing rating filters now/still on Chromium... :(

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Google maps App, you can search for 'Restaurants', and then filter for 'Open Now'.

[image]

I only use it on iOS, but I'm quite sure Google maps on Android does it too.

Comment: It seems as though that option isn't there in android maps - when I select filters the only filter is based on rating.

Comment: Serioulsy?? Google's version for iOS is better than for their own OS??? Maybe you have an older version, I am not following Android versions, there is all that "Peach Gummiring 3.4" stuff that only runs on certain devices. But it really surprises me.

Comment: Let's not get ahead of ourselves, it's possible there are criteria for displaying the filter that haven't been met. The filter pages look very similar

Comment: I never gave the down vote

Comment: i guessed; it came in the same ten seconds of your answer. i deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, now (in 2022), I just found (after googling for this quiestion), that there is an "opening hours" drop down at the top of the map which allows you to filter on things which are "open now"...